# Logic error of cumulative statement and lag function

Tags: sas

This task is going to derive a time-series variable, The rule is:

> X(t) = 1.5 * X(t-1) - 0.5 * X(t-2) + e;
> X(1) = e;
> X(2) = 1.5 * X(1) + e;

where e ~ N(0,1). Here is how I generate this sequence:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(42);
  do i=1 to 200;
    e=rand("normal",0,1);
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  set have;

  *Method 1;
  x+sum(0.5*x,-0.5*lag(x),e);

  *Method 2;
  y+0.5*y-0.5*lag(y)+e;

  *Method 3;
  retain z;
  if _n_=1 then z=e;
  if _n_=2 then z=1.5*z+e;

  lag2_z=lag2(z);
  if _n_>2 then z=1.5*z-0.5*lag2_z+e;
run;
```

Run this code, I just find only result of method 1 is right. Why Method 2 and Method 3 are wrong? How to fix them?
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum()` function ignores missing values in it's summation.

The `sum` statement also ignores missing values, however the `summand` in method 2 is normal arithmetic sum with `lag(y)` which is missing and thus the `e` never gets into play at `t=2`. In other words, at t=1 `0.5*y-0.5*lag(y)+e` is missing.

Method 3. is hiccupping because the lag2 for *n*>2 is before the recalculated z

Adding these to output might help you suss it out in your head.

```
  * method 3;
  retain z;
  if _n_=1 then z=e;
  if _n_=2 then z=1.5*z+e;

  lag2_z=lag2(z);
  pre_z = z;

  if _n_>2 then z=1.5*z-0.5*lag2_z+e;
```

Comment: Thank you, Richard, I use a `lag()` function to instead `lag2()` and move it before `retain` statement now.

Answer (score 1):

*Data:*
I would go with a bit simpler data, e.g.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(42);
  do i=1 to 20;
    e=1; /*rand("normal",0,1);*/
    output;
  end;
run;
```

*Metchod1:*

This `x+sum(0.5*x,-0.5*lag(x),e);` is different from `X(t) = 1.5 * X(t-1) - 0.5 * X(t-2) + e;`, you are missing `1` in `0.5`.

*Method2:*

In the first iteration this expression `0.5*y-0.5*lag(y)+e;` evaluates to missing (`.`) since lag(y) is missing, so the sum statement is in fact `y+.;` which gives wrong result.

*Method3:*

Add some `put` statements to see how it calculates, e.g.

```
  *Method 3;
  retain z;

  put z= lag2_z= e=;
  if _n_=1 then z=e;
  if _n_=2 then z=1.5*z+e;

  lag2_z=lag2(z);
  put z= lag2_z= e=;
  if _n_>2 then z=1.5*z-0.5*lag2_z+e;
  put _N_ z= / /;
```

I would do it like this:

```
%let n = 100;
%let e=1; /* change 1 to Rand() */
/*
%let e = rand("normal",0,1);
*/

data want;

  call streaminit(42);

  e=&e.;
  a=e;
  output;
  b=1.5*a + e;
  output;

  do i=1 to &n.-2;
    e=&e.;
    c= 1.5 * b - 0.5 * a + e;
    a=b;
    b=c;
  put _all_;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, yabwon. very detailed. I think you just missing a statement ` e=&e.; ` after the first `output` statement. after I add this statement and modify some parameter, your algorithm just has the same result as my method 1. The `x+sum(0.5*x,...)` is not wrong, it is equal to `retain x 0; x=sum(x,sum(0.5*x,...))`, comes out `1.5*x`. Thank you anyway, your anwser give me more inspiration.